# How to make math font huge

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I would like to typeset a simple-to-medium-difficulty math formula on an A4/letter paper. It needs to be huge and preferably centered and portrait.

I can take care of the paper size, the orientation — but not the centering and font size.

Any resources you can recommend?

Comment: Related Question: [Reducing font size in equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `graphicx` package provides the command `\resizebox`. The `lscape` package provides the `landscape` environment.

Together they could be used as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
 \resizebox{20cm}{!}{$e^{i\pi}=-1$}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `\resizebox` takes arguments `\resizebox{width}{height}`. In the above I have used `{!}` for the height to ensure that the aspect ratio remains true- otherwise you might get ugly stretched boxes.

Answer (score 17):

There are several ways to do this:

1. You can use `\scalebox` from [the `graphicx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/graphics/).
2. Use [the `relsize` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/relsize).
3. Use `\DeclareMathSizes` but that will affect the entire document.

Here is the normal, and scaled result using the `\scalebox` solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}}%
\begin{document}
\[y = \sin^2 x\]
%
\[\Scale[6]{y = \sin^2 x}\]
\end{document}
```

Or, using the `relsize` package, but it did not appear to get larger using a factor larger than 5.  Perhaps there is a way to adjust this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\[y = \sin^2 x\]
%
\larger[5]
\[y = \sin^2 x\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\resize` change the font size **relative** to the current size. Moreover, this is only done in the regular font size intervals. That is, `\larger[1]` in `\normalsize` is equivalent to `\large`, or `\relsize{-2}` in `\small` is equivalent to `\scriptsize`. As such, this is typically limited to `\tiny` (on the lower end) and `\Huge` (on the upper end). That is reason why a "factor" (or "magnification step") of `5`, which equates to `\Huge` in `\normalsize` yields the biggest difference (making `6` or higher superfluous).

Comment: \scalebox does a fine job for me. Thanks Peter!