# Equations, change the font size

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

How do I change the font size of something like this:  I want to increase the font but it always seems to remain the same.

```
 \documentclass[30pt]{article}
 \DeclareMathSizes{20}{20}{20}{20}
 \begin{document}

 \[
   x = \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}}
 \]

 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510611/latex-equations-change-the-font-size?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: @jfbu: This comment will be deleted shortly. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @cmhughes: your link points to 404. I will delete this comment shortly (if I don't forget it).

Answer (score 15):

The first parameter of `\DeclareMathSizes` specifies the font size to which these settings are applied to.  So, for a `12pt` document, if the first parameter is not `12`, then this command will have no effect.  So for the code as below, the output is:

[image]

but with the line `\DeclareMathSizes{12}{24}{24}{24}` un-commented you get:

[image]

Also see [How to make math font huge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31416/how-to-make-math-font-huge/).

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
% \DeclareMathSizes{12}{24}{24}{24}% Uncomment to see the effect
\begin{document}
\[
   x = \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

no need to redefine the math sizes: use `\dfrac` from `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}

 \[
   x = \dfrac{1}{x + \dfrac{1}{x + \dfrac{1}{x}}}
 \]
\Huge
 \[
   x = \dfrac{1}{x + \dfrac{1}{x + \dfrac{1}{x}}}
 \]

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much better approach then the accepted answer…