# Equal font sizes in equation while using Beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, fontsize

> This is a follow-up question to [Equations, change the font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/equations-change-the-font-size/73356)

I was trying to have equal font sizes in equations like the ones in the above link. Using `\DeclareMathSizes{display size}{text size}{script size}{subscript size}` gives me desired effects in article, exam classes but no effect in beamer slides.

Any suggestion please to see the effects in beamer slides!

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{24}{24}{24}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test equation to have a same font size}
    \[
           x = \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}}
    \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and its output is:
[image]

Comment: Add the `12pt` class option as in my example: `\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}`, or use `\makeatletter\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{24}{24}{24}\makeatother` as egreg suggested.
.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, Oh sorry, `yes, it works after putting 12pt in class option`. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While methods given by @GonzaloMedina and @egreg work perfectly fine in cases, I have also found another method from `wikibook from here->` http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics. 
Very handy to use command: `\everymath{\displaystyle}` in the preamble. You can also use in the **localized equation** like:

```
\begin{equation}
x = a_0 + \frac{1}{\displaystyle a_1
      + \frac{1}{\displaystyle a_2
      + \frac{1}{\displaystyle a_3 + a_4}}}
\end{equation}
```

Note: `\DeclareMathSizes{display size}{text size}{script size}{subscript size}` failed in one of my big beamer file which has tikz along with many other packages.

Comment: You should check the `\cfrac` macro provided by `amsmath`. For this application `\DeclareMathSizes` is clearly overkill.

Comment: @egreg, thank you. I saw that too just now in `amsmdoc`. Yes, `\DeclareMathSizes` makes overlapping of numerator and denominator expressions sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

The default text size used by `beamer` is `11pt`, which must be referred to as `\@xipt`. Just for an example I tried very big math font sizes, using the Arev fonts to overcome problems in font loading:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{arevtext,arevmath}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{50}{40}{30}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Text $m_{a}+t+\sqrt{h}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Similar declarations should be made for the other sizes, if you plan to use math in `\large`, `\small` or similar contexts.

However, I don't think that changing the math sizes is a good thing to do.

---

After seeing the minimal example and the real problem you have, I suggest you to use the `\cfrac` command provided by `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test equation to have a same font size}
    \[
           x = \cfrac{1}{x + \cfrac{1}{x + \cfrac{1}{x}}}
    \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` in an equation can also have the desired effect. For in-line math mode you should always use `\frac`, but on display mode `\dfrac` looks better in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same method as customizing the normal text size  ...

```
\fontsize{9.5}{7.2}{
 \begin{equation}
\psi = \psi^{s}+\tilde{\psi} 
 \end{equation}  
}
```