# How to scale all mathematics of a document

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equations, change the font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/equations-change-the-font-size)
>   [How to scale math font only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only)

I am very new to LaTeX. I want all maths to be shown larger text. Is it possible? If so, how?

Here is an an MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[xetex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Adib}

%Defining fonts
\font\e="Times New Roman" at 12pt
\font\lb="SolaimanLipi-Bold:script=beng" at 22pt
\font\b="SolaimanLipi:script=beng" at 14pt
\font\bl="SolaimanLipi-Bold:script=beng" at 14pt
\begin{document}
\title{\lb{অণুসম গণিত}}
\date{}
\maketitle
\b{নাম্বার থিয়োরি ভালোবাসেন কিন্তু কনগ্রুয়েন্স বা অনুসমতা সম্পর্কে ধারণা নেই এমন মানুষ একটিও সম্ভবত
এই ধরাধামে খুঁজে পাওয়া যাবে না। কারণ ক্লাসিক্যাল নাম্বার থিয়োরির খুব বড় একটি অংশই যে রয়েছে এই
মডুলার এরিথম্যাটিকের দখলে।

এবার ভূমিকা ছেড়ে মূল আলোচনায় আসা যাক। $a$ এবং $b$ সংখ্যা দুটিকে যদি $c$ দ্বারা ভাগ করে 
একই ভাগশেষ পাওয়া যায় তবে বলা হয়} \bl{$a$ এবং $b$ হচ্ছে $c$ ভাজকের সাপেক্ষে অনুসম বা 
কনগ্রুয়েন্ট।} \b{কিংবা গণিতের ভাষায় $a\equiv b\pmod c$}
\b{ পড়তে হয়} '\e{$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $c$}'
\end{document}
```

Edit: Thank you all of you guys for such excellent answers.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do so? Because I'm _sure_ it won't look pleasantly at all.

Comment: yeah, I know. Actually I'm using XeTeX to write in Unicode. While using it I found that all mathematics are in 10pt size and whenever I change the font size of the whole document, it does not apply to the font size of mathematics. That's why I was wondering if there is any way to control the size of only mathematics.

Comment: Have you tried using the 12pt option to the documentclass as in `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` ?

Comment: It sounds like you are not loading the mathematics fonts in the correct way.  Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: yeah, using \documentclass[12pt]{article} does not fix that issue. Also I tried to change font size of a particular area, but still I'm unable to change the math font size.

Comment: There is no `14pt` option for the `article` class, so you end up with the default 10pt. Using `\font` in LaTeX is never a good idea: use the facilities of `fontspec` for that.

Comment: Can you clarify, please?

Comment: When you write `\documentclass[1000pt]{article}`, then the `1000` is ignored, becuase there is no suport for it. Only `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt` can be used.

Answer (score 9):

There are several problems with your code.

To get the `article` class with the `14pt` option you need to use `extarticle` instead.

Using the `\font` command is not the recommended way of working with `fontspec`.  It is better to load the font families and then use sizing commands of LaTeX, e.g. `\large` etc. or for other sizes `\fontsize{a}{b}\selectfont`, where `a` is the desired fontsize in points and `b` is the baselineskip.

Thirdly there is a problem with math scaling if you use standard latex set-up at large sizes.  This is corrected by the `fix-cm` package.

Below is an example using a non-exotic font:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,fix-cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\fontspec{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
{$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $c$}

\medskip

{\fontsize{100}{106}\selectfont Huge $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $c$\par }
\end{document}
```

For your other fonts, consider using the `\newfontfamily` as follows:

```
\newfontfamily{\lipi}[Script=beng}{SolaimanLipi}
```

I don't have this font available to test, but if all is well you should be able to use `\lipi` to switch to this collection of fonts and use `\textbf` etc. to change to bold versions.  If these are to be the main document fonts, then load them with the `\fontspec` command instead, and define a separate command for the Times New Roman instead.

Now if you still really want the mathematics to be bigger than the standard text you can use `fontspec` via `unicode-math` in the following type of way, loading your choice of math font with an extra `Scale` option:

[image: Sample scaled math]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[Scale=2.5]{xits-math.otf}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $c$

\medskip

{\fontsize{30}{34}\selectfont Huge $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo
$c$}

\end{document}
```

Of course, with this exaggerated maths scaling the sizing command should probably be more like `\fontsize{30}{80}` to allow space for the large characters.

Comment: +1 I also stole your example to use in my answer (which relies on having fonts set up right as you note here)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks - the final part of my answer was delayed by not knowing that `xelatex`s way of finding fonts - `lualatex` is so much easier.  The example phrase used is actually from the end of the poster's code.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Your example uses primitive `\font` commands which cut through the LaTeX font mechanism. If you don't do that and always declare fonts via latex font declaration commands then the size of fonts used in mathematics is controlled by `\DeclareMathSizes` For example this declares that if the text font is 12pt then the math font should be 20pt (and 16pt in subscripts and 12pt in subsubscripts)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,fix-cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\fontspec{Times New Roman}
 \DeclareMathSizes{12}{20}{16}{12}

\begin{document}
$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $c$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll let this answer stand as it answers the original question and may be useful to others. However as clarified in comments you do _not_ want to do this. The reason that the math and text fonts were not at the same size was that you were using primitive font commands so not giving font LaTeX mechanisms any information. If you declare the sizes using LaTeX declarations as in the other two answers math and text will match.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want 14pt main size, use `extarticle`; since your default language seems Bengali, it's better to use Polyglossia:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily{\termes}[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TG Termes Math}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\newcommand{\bl}[1]{#1} % the FreeSerif font doesn't have bold face
% \newcommand{\bl}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % uncomment this for your font

\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{\termes #1}}

\begin{document}

\author{Adib}
\title{অণুসম গণিত}
\date{}
\maketitle

নাম্বার থিয়োরি ভালোবাসেন কিন্তু কনগ্রুয়েন্স বা অনুসমতা সম্পর্কে ধারণা নেই এমন
মানুষ একটিও সম্ভবত এই ধরাধামে খুঁজে পাওয়া যাবে না। কারণ ক্লাসিক্যাল নাম্বার
থিয়োরির খুব বড় একটি অংশই যে রয়েছে এই মডুলার এরিথম্যাটিকের দখলে।

এবার ভূমিকা ছেড়ে মূল আলোচনায় আসা যাক। $a$ এবং $b$ সংখ্যা দুটিকে যদি $c$
দ্বারা ভাগ করে একই ভাগশেষ পাওয়া যায় তবে বলা হয় \bl{$a$ এবং $b$ হচ্ছে
$c$ ভাজকের সাপেক্ষে অনুসম বা কনগ্রুয়েন্ট।} কিংবা গণিতের ভাষায় $a\equiv
b \pmod{c}$ পড়তে হয় \eng{`$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo
$c$'}

\end{document}
```

I've got no other Bengali font, so I disabled boldface, which isn't available with FreeSerif.

[image]

Comment: +1 As I note in a comment on my answer, I answered the original question as written, but this is what the OP should do (as clarified in comments on the question).