# Can I make formulae thicker?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, math-mode

I've just created an [SVG version with TikZ](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vector-triangle-inequality.svg) and Inkscape from an [old PNG version](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_triangle_inequality.PNG) of an image on wikipedia. This is how they look like:

[image: images compared]

You might notice, that the text of the left image is much easier to read. One reason is the color, but the othr is defitely the font.

**How can I make the text easier to read?**

I thick making the text (all formulae) bold would be a good start. If this isn't enough, it might be necessary to change from the italic font to a normal one.

The [current source is on github](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/blob/master/tikz/vector-triangle-inequality/vector-triangle-inequality.tex). Here is the source that was used for the image above:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes, arrows} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{xvectorcolor}{HTML}{77933C}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % Punkte
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0) {};
    \coordinate (B) at (5,0) {};
    \coordinate (C) at (2,2) {};

    % Draw the triangle
    \path[fill=blue!10, fill=blue!10]  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
    \draw[->, ultra thick,fill=gray!10, xvectorcolor, arrows={-latex}]  (A) -- (C) node[sloped,midway,above] {$x$};
    \draw[->, ultra thick,fill=gray!10, blue!80, arrows={-latex}]  (C) -- (B) node[sloped,midway,above] {$y$};
    \draw[->, ultra thick,fill=gray!10, red!80, arrows={-latex}]  (A) -- (B) node[sloped,midway,above] {$z = x + y$};
    \coordinate  (A) -- (B) node[sloped,midway,below] {$\|z\| = \|x+y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$};



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just add `font=\boldmath` to the `tikzpicture` options to make the math bold.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good hint. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24040/5645 were also some good hints, but `\mathsf{...}` provided the best result so far.

Comment: Computer modern is a thin font. Maybe you should try times-like font, such as package `mathptmx` or `txfonts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of the following variant is that the long formula at the bottom determines the width of the triangle (line `AB`).

- It uses `\boldmath` for the symbols (`=`, `+`, …) and a sans serif font for the variables (`\mathsf` wanted in comment).
- The spacing inside the formulas can be adjusted by `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`. The former controls the spacing around binary operators (`+`), the latter around relational symbols (`=`).
- The example uses `line cap=round` to make the overlapping at `A` a little nicer.

The complete example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes, arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tgheros}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{xvectorcolor}{HTML}{77933C}

\medmuskip=.75\medmuskip
%\thickmuskip=.75\thickmuskip

\newcommand*{\sy}[1]{\textsf{% \itshape
  #1%
}}

\newsavebox\formula
\newdimen\Coff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\boldmath,
  ultra thick,
]
  \node[line width=0pt,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt] (eq) {%
    \sbox\formula{$
      \|\sy z\| = \|\sy x+\sy y\| \leq \|\sy x\| + \|\sy y\|
    $}%
    \usebox\formula
    \global\Coff=.4\wd\formula
  };
  \coordinate (A) at ($(eq.north west) + (1.6pt,1ex)$);
  \coordinate (B) at ($(eq.north east) + (-1.6pt,1ex)$);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(A) + (\Coff,\Coff)$);
  \path[fill=blue!10, fill=blue!10]  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
  \draw[->, fill=gray!10, xvectorcolor, arrows={-latex}]
    (A) -- (C) node[sloped,midway,above] {$\sy x$};
  \draw[->, fill=gray!10, blue!80, arrows={-latex}]
    (C) -- (B) node[sloped,midway,above] {$\sy y$};
  \draw[->, fill=gray!10, red!80, arrows={-latex}, line cap=round]
    (A) -- (B) node[sloped,midway,above] {$\sy z = \sy x + \sy y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

Jake's suggestion of using `font=\boldmath` goes a long way towards what you want.
But if that is not enough you can increase it further via `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package:

[image]

### References:

- [How to make math font huge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31416/how-to-make-math-font-huge/)
- [Reducing font size in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation/)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes, arrows} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{xvectorcolor}{HTML}{77933C}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][1.5]{\scalebox{#1}{#2}}%


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\boldmath]
    % Punkte
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0) {};
    \coordinate (B) at (5,0) {};
    \coordinate (C) at (2,2) {};

    % Draw the triangle
    \path[fill=blue!10, fill=blue!10]  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
    \draw[->, ultra thick,fill=gray!10, xvectorcolor, arrows={-latex}]  (A) -- (C) node[sloped,midway,above] {\Scale{$x$}};
    \draw[->, ultra thick,fill=gray!10, blue!80, arrows={-latex}]  (C) -- (B) node[sloped,midway,above] {\Scale{$y$}};
    \draw[->, ultra thick,fill=gray!10, red!80, arrows={-latex}]  (A) -- (B) node[sloped,midway,above] {\Scale{$z = x + y$}};
    \coordinate  (A) -- (B) node[sloped,midway,below] {\Scale{$\|z\| = \|x+y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess before using `scalebox`, one could first try `\large` or `\Large`. Also, instead of wrapping the text in a `\scalebox`, one could simply say `every node/.style={scale=1.5}`.

Comment: Scaling text isn't the right solution. Bigger text has to be ``thinner'' in general. `<sarcasm>` Then again, most people won't notice this, which may explain why `w*rd` is still so popular. `</sarcasm>`