# \left \right for the bracket of a function

Tags: brackets

I'm writing something like a function `Y(-)`, where the term in the bracket is large, so I wrote `Y\left(-\right)`, however, the "Y" is still the normal size, which makes it looks small, compare with the `\left(` next to it. And the space between the two is large. Anybody can help me with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `\mleft` and `\mright` of package `mleftright` avoid the additional spacing of `\left` and `\right`.
- I would not increase the size of `Y`. It looks odd, if it is then be combined with unscaled versions. Also scaling increases the boldness of the glyph.

  The arguemnt can be decreased with a smaller math style depending on its contents. In case of a fraction `\textstyle` helps, if the fraction is in a displayed equation (`\displaystyle`).

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}
\[ Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \]
\[ Y\mleft(\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\mright) \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I believe there exists a `\tfrac` in `amsmath` ;)

Answer (score 4):

The `\left`, `\right` construct is intended to scale the braces, not the preceding text. However, you can use something like `\scalebox` to scale the preceding text, and apply a `\kern` to shift the paren to the left.  To make sure that the `Y` is aligned I use `\raisebox` to move it down slighlty (adjust the parameters to suit).

Here is a normal usage, `\scalebox` applied to the `Y` and, a `\scalebox` followed by a `\kern`:

[image]

### Notes:

- As Heiko Oberdiek, and Barbara Beeton have pointed out scaling one character in such a context is usually not really a good idea, so use with care.

### References:

- [How to make math font huge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31416/how-to-make-math-font-huge)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\LargeY}{\raisebox{-0.40ex}{\scalebox{1.5}{$Y$}}}%

\begin{document}\noindent
\[
    Y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
    \quad\LargeY\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
    \quad\LargeY\kern-0.4em\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: how about the space between Y and ()?

Comment: Updated example to show how to reduce the space between the `Y` and `(`.

Comment: @PeterGrill -- when the `Y` is scaled, its height increases (as intended), but now it looks very unbalanced with respect to the math axis (the relative height of the fraction bar).  maybe this looks better in a more elaborate context, but alone it looks like it is trying to be a "large operator" (like a sum), and fails miserably.  without knowing the intent of this request, my immediate reaction is that it is misguided.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Totally agree.   Did not intend to be advocating enlarging the text, just providing a way to do what the OP desired.  I have updated to apply a `\raisebox` to shift the scaled `Y` down slightly.

Answer (score 2):

You could load the `relsize` package and use its command `\mathlarger` on the symbol `Y`, i.e., `\mathlarger{Y}`. Continue to use `\left` and `\right` on the parentheses.