# Spacing around \left and \right: When is it needed?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators, brackets, delimiters

There have been a few questions (such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right) and more recently [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82815/left-right-for-the-bracket-of-a-function)) regarding the "extra" spacing around `\left` and `\right`.  And there are various options for fixing it, including the `mleftright` package.  Is there any time we would actually **want** the default behavior?  Is there any situation in which redefining `\left` and `\right` to get rid of the space would produce an inferior result?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really an answerable question in this form. Clearly _someone_ preferred this behaviour as it is not an accidental side effect in the code of TeX, the whole mathinner node type is introduced to produce this effect. Personally I think it works out OK when the delimiters are being used around matrices or large subterms generally. It works a lot less well in conjunction with a mathop where you have a prefix function name nut need big brackets.

Comment: I like this question a lot, and was thinking about asking it myself; I was wondering what the consequences of trying something like `\left\left\mleft`...

Comment: opps, I meant to say `\let\left\mleft`

Comment: See The TeX Book, p.155 : "There's also an eighth classification, `\mathinner`, which is not normally used for individual symbols; fractions and `\left...\right` constructions are treated as "inner" subformulas, which means that they will be surrounded by additional space in certain circumstances."

Comment: And as the preceding paragraph on the page makes clear, if you want to treat it differently you can do by using one of the `\mathxxxx` primitives to change it into a different math atom.  In the particular case referred to in the above questions all that is needed is to do something like `$\cos\mathopen{\left(\theta\right)}$`, which turns the `\left(\theta\right)` part into a mathopen atom instead of a mathinner and because ( is normally defined as a mathopen atom, this produces the same spacing as an unadorned `\cos(\theta)`.