# Resizing LaTeX Math mode font

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I have a simple LaTeX document here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{setspace}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\setmainfont{THSarabunNew}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

    \fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont
    \textbf{\underline{ตอนที่ 1} ข้อสอบแบบเลือกตอบ 6 ตัวเลือก จำนวน 10 ข้อ ข้อละ 2 คะแนน}\\
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont
\indent\indent จงหาจำนวนของจำนวนนับ  $ n $  ทั้งหมดที่เป็นไปได้ซึ่ง $ 143\leq n\leq 1143 $  และจำนวน   กับ   มีเลขโดดในหลักพัน หรือหลักหมื่น แตกต่างกัน\\
a. $ 609 $      b. $ 700 $      c. $ 701 $      d. $ 854 $      e. $ 855 $
\end{document}
```

The thing is, the font `THSarabunNew` is rather small compared to the math mode text (that's why is use the text font at 20 and 18), thus making the math mode looks pretty large. I want to know how to customise the math mode font size *without* preceeding `\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont` (which is smaller) for every math equation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say `\setmainfont[Scale=1.4]{THSarabunNew}`?

Comment: @Sarun: Several possibilites are shown in the second answer to this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31416/how-to-make-math-font-huge). Maybe one of those is useful for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than increasing the size in the document, load the font at a larger scale:

```
\documentclass{article}

\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.5]{THSarabunNew.ttf}

\begin{document}

{\large
ตอนที่ 1 ข้อสอบแบบเลือกตอบ 6 ตัวเลือก จำนวน 10 ข้อ ข้อละ 2 คะแนน

}

จงหาจำนวนของจำนวนนับ $ n $ ทั้งหมดที่เป็นไปได้ซึ่ง $ 143\leq n\leq 1143 $ และจำนวน กับ มีเลขโดดในหลักพัน หรือหลักหมื่น
แตกต่างกัน\\ a. $ 609 $ b. $ 700 $ c. $ 701 $ d. $ 854 $ e. $ 855 $

\end{document}
```

[image]