# Larger math symbols in LaTeX

Tags: formatting

Is it possible to get LaTeX to use large math symbols like the ones shown in this photo?  This is the typesetting scheme used in older math books.

[image]

By default, my LaTeX produces math symbols that are smaller, please see photo below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.}}{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0in} 
\input{tcilatex} 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\dfrac{}{}`?

Comment: larger than what? it is very difficult to gauge size just from an image, the symbols don't look particularly large, only odd thing is the over-large space under the fraction bar (presumably designed so 1/e aligns with 1/e^2 so not totally unreasonable)

Comment: Please see my updated question.  I have included a second illustration.  Notice that in the second photo, the addition, subtraction and equal sign are smaller relative to the numbers.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) What is your setup is like, could your provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: @RobinGrajeda: you might want to put your minimal working example into your question instead of a comment.

Comment: Maybe useful for you:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31416/5590

Comment: Package `mathabx` provides the `\bigplus` macro.

Answer (score 1):

The first image of the question can be generated by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}
\[
  \newcommand*{\e}{\mathrm{e}}% Euler constant
   g(\e) = m + 2 - \e^2,\quad
   g(\e) - g\mleft(\frac{1}{\e}\mright) = -\e^2 + \frac{1}{\e^2} < 0
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

I cannot see any reason to increase the size of math symbols (`+`, `-`, `=`, `<`. The size for the latter in the image of the question is quite too large. Also the default horizontal spacing is much better in TeX (e.g. around binary and relational operators).

BTW, there was an error in the math, corrected here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
 \resizebox{7cm}{!}{$g(e)=m+2-e^2 \cdots$}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You can play around with the `\resizebox` cm value

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is not what I am looking for.  I do not want to increase the size of everything, but only the size of the plus / minus sign relative to the numbers.  This code increases the size of the font for everything.

Comment: May I ask is there any specific purpose that you want to increase the sign relative to the numbers?

Comment: It is purely for aesthetic reasons.  I notice that books published prior to 1970's used this larger symbol set.  Also, the Chinese Gao Kao practice books still use it.  I would like to be able to reproduce this result.