# How can I change the size of one symbol in an equation?

Tags: equations, fontsize

I want to use a symbol `f` in some of my equations *(to denote a very important function)*, and I want it to stand out, so I was thinking of boosting its size. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way of enlarging particular parts within an equation, as opposed to enlarging an equation as a whole *(with, [for instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60457), `\scalebox`from `graphicx` package)* or shrinking a particular part *(with, [for instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31417), `\scriptsize` of `mathtools`)*. Of course, I could make  a separate equation for every `f`, but this would be quite messy in practice, and it is hard to phrase as a `\newcommand` *(and I definitely want a `\newcommand{\f}` for this)*.

So, is there a way I can go about obtaining the enlarged `f` in math mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
\newcommand{\bigf}{\text{\Large $f$}}
```

and then use

```
\bigf
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `relsize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\fso}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{f}}}% f stand out

\begin{document}

Standard $f$ and larger $\mathlarger{f}$,
with even larger $\mathlarger{\mathlarger{f}}$

$\fso(x)\ne f(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]