# "Beautifully" resize math align block (font and symbols)

Tags: fonts, amsmath, relsize

I'm using `\mathlarger` from `relsize` package to get larger fonts in my beamer presentation (in some VERY special cases, not to all equations). But the symbols are not scaling correctly, I'm mostly worried about the integral symbol. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x) dx = f(1) - f(0)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x) dx = f(1) - f(0)}}
\end{align*}

\begin{landscape}
     \begin{center}
        \resizebox{7cm}{!}{$\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x) dx = f(1) - f(0)$}
     \end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As proof of concept

[image: First: regular; second: \mathlarger; third: \resizebox]
First: `regular`; second: `\mathlarger`; third: `\resizebox`

Just the regular has the nicely fit integral symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make math font huge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31416/how-to-make-math-font-huge)

Comment: no, isn't a dupicate, that solution also do not give beautiful symbols. I tried. And we are here for the beauty, otherwise we could just use word equation editor.

Comment: I made a single frame from your example just to have a single picture; and [here (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXnHF.png) is the result. No issue for me, as you see.

Comment: Same remark as @egreg’s, plus `\showoutput` confirms that the smaller integral sign is taken from `\OMX/cmex/m/n/10.95`, while the second comes from `\OMX/cmex/m/n/14.4`.

Comment: Are you perhaps doing `\usepackage{lmodern}` in your document? The example with `\resizebox` should have `$\displaystyle...$`

Comment: indeed I'm, let me remove it.

Comment: Issue was lmodern. Let me add to OP.

Comment: Yes, it is well known: `lmodern` loads `lmex` fonts (that take the place of `cmex` ones) at fixed size.  I too was suspecting you were using that package.  It is possible to add a patch and still use it, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->lmex10%
   }{}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x) dx = f(1) - f(0)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(x) dx = f(1) - f(0)}}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The issue arises because the `omxlmex.fd` file, which tells TeX where to look to find the TFM file for the `lmex` family (the family that the `lmodern` package uses as a replacement for the `cmex` one — in other words, for the “large symbols) loads the `cmex10.tfm` file at a fixed size equal to the design size.  Actually, the `omxcmex.fd` prescribe exactly the same behavior for the `cmex` family, but the `amsfonts` package (and also, albeit to a limited extent, the `amsmath` package) add a patch to correct this.  The `amsfonts` (and `amsmath`) packages do not care about the `lmex` family, though: this is why one needs to introduce the corresponding patch by hand, when the `lmodern` package is used.  This is exactly what the lines

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->lmex10%
   }{}
```

do.

Comment: `\usepackage{fixcmex}`

Comment: @egreg: Oh, nice!  And, yes, I cannot recollect having ever noticed this package of yours—my apologies.  But now I have a question: when the Latin Modern fonts are used, you revert the `largesymbols` font to OMX/cmex; I assume you do so to because there are no `lmex7`, `lmex8`, and `lmex9` fonts available.  The question is: why is this the case?  Why nobody ever thought of designing smaller versions of the `lmex10` font?

Comment: Ask the developers of Latin Modern. The issue has been known for years.