# How can I make the underbraced bigger?

Tags: math-mode, underbrace

I have to kind of underbraces:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:romberg2}
M=N\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)+\underbrace{K_{1}\frac{h}{2}+K_{2}\frac{h^{2}}{4}+K_{3}\frac{h^{3}}{8}+\hdots}_{\text{\normalsize{Error}}}
\end{equation}
```

which works well (except from the not-centered "Error"), and:

```
\begin{equation}
M=\underbrace{N\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)+\left[N\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)-N(h)\right]}_{N_{2}(h)}+K_{2}\left(\frac{h^{2}}{2}-h^{2}\right)+K_{3}\left(\frac{h^{3}}{4}-h^{3}\right)+\hdots
\end{equation}
```

which makes my `$N_{2}(h)$` small. I have tried using `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\big`, etc. inside the underbrace but didn´t make any difference.

Do you know how to make the `$N_{2}(h)$` bigger? and how can I center the underbraced "Error" from the first equation?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!. You could use `\displaystyle`: `\begin{equation}
M=\underbrace{N\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)+\left[N\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)-N(h)\right]}_{\displaystyle
N_{2}(h)}+K_{2}\left(\frac{h^{2}}{2}-h^{2}\right)+K_{3}\left(\frac{h^{3}}{4}-h^{3}\right)+\hdots
\end{equation}`

Comment: You can also load the `graphicx` package and place the `$N_2(h)$` in a `\scalebox` - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31417/172926

Comment: I think the “Error” text is centered, but it *looks* off center. That is a visual illusion, I think. You could try adding a space, as in `\text{\normalsize{Error }}`, to shove it left a bit. Or a suitable `\hspace` if the regular space is too big. (By the way, the inner pair of curly braces are not needed. I left them in to make it clear not to confuse you with yet another space that will be gobbled up.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\textstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
M=N\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)+
{\underbrace{
  K_{1}\frac{h}{2}+K_{2}\frac{h^{2}}{4}+K_{3}\frac{h^{3}}{8}+\dotsb
}_{\textstyle\text{Error}}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
M={\underbrace{
  N\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)+\left[N\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)-N(h)\right]
}_{\textstyle N_{2}(h)}}+
K_{2}\left(\frac{h^{2}}{2}-h^{2}\right)+K_{3}\left(\frac{h^{3}}{4}-h^{3}\right)+
\dotsb
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember the braces around the `\underbrace` construction, or the spacing around it might be wrong.

I'd remark that `\hdots` is not the right command in that case and `\dotsb` is better.

Comment: Kind @egreg, please can I know the difference between the use `\cdots` and `\dotsb` that have you used?

Comment: @Sebastiano See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122497/4427